# How to add specific conditions to stepAIC

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am running a regression with 37 variables, and I am using `stepAIC` to perform model selection. I do NOT want a predictive model. I just want to find out what varibles have the best explanatory power.

My current code looks like:

```
fitObject <- lm(mydata)
DEP.select <- stepAIC(fitObject, direction = 'both', scope= list(lower = ~AUC), trace = F, k = log(obs))
# DEP is my dependent variable, and AUC is an independent variable I was want to have in my model.
```

The problem is that a lot of my variables have high correlation, and the result `stepAIC` gives me contains several of those highly correlated variables. Notice that I have forced AUC in the model, multicollinearity is a problem especially when those variables highly correlated with AUC are chosen in the model.

Is there a way to specify in the function some thresholds for correlation or p-value of the coefficients?

Or any comments on other approaches that can solve my problem are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: you haven't even specified a model in lm?

Comment: This is to regress all variables on the first variable of the data frame. same as `fitObject <- lm(mydata[,1]~., data=mydata)`

Comment: I understand that, but it is very prone to all sorts of unwanted things. but to answer your question, no, you are using AIC as model selection so pvalues are irrelevant. And just because some variables are collinear does not imply that they are useless. What are your goals? are you trying to find a predictive model? Do you have some idea of which variables should be in the model even if their pvalues are not "good enough?" These mechanical model selection algorithms are generally not great

Comment: I understand the problems with model selection, and this is not my final model. I just want to pick out the variables that can explain my dependent variable. All the variables are relavant (some are similar), and that's why there is so much correlation. I have updated my question a little about my goal. Any advice on other ways to tacle the problem is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Variance Inflation Factor will work better for you.  This article explains some of the logic.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor

Example use:

```
v=ezvif(df,yvar ='columnNameOfWhichYouAreTryingToPredict')
```

Here is the function I wrote that combines VIF::vif with cross validation.

```
require(VIF)
require(cvTools);
#returns selected variables using VIF and kfolds cross validation 
ezvif=function(df,yvar,folds=5,trace=F){
  f=cvFolds(nrow(df),K=folds);
  findings=list();
  for(v in names(df)){
    if(v==yvar)next;
    findings[[v]]=0; 
  }
  for(i in 1:folds){   
    rows=f$subsets[f$which!=i]
    y=df[rows,yvar];
    xdf=df[rows,names(df) != yvar]; #remove output var    
    vifResult=vif(y,xdf,trace=trace,subsize=min(200,floor(nrow(xdf))))
    for(v in names(xdf)[vifResult$select]){
      findings[[v]]=findings[[v]]+1; #vote
    }
  }
  findings=(sort(unlist(findings),decreasing = T))    
  if(trace) print(findings[findings>0]); 
  return( c(yvar,names(findings[findings==findings[1]])) )  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove the variables with high correlations. The libraries caret and corrplot can help:

```
library(corrplot)
library(caret)
dm = data.matrix(mydata[,names(mydata) != 'DEP'] #without your outcome var
```

Visualize your correlations clustering highly correlated together

```
corrplot(cor(dm), order = 'hclust')
```

And find the indices of variables that you could remove due to high (>0.75) correlations

```
findCorrelations(cor(dm), 0.75)
```

Removing these variables can improve your model. After removing the variables, continue doing the stepAIC as you described in your question.

Answer (score -1):

To assess multicollinearity between predictors when running the dredge function (MuMIn package), include the following max.r function as the "extra" argument:

```
max.r <- function(x){
  corm <- cov2cor(vcov(x))
  corm <- as.matrix(corm)
  if (length(corm)==1){
    corm <- 0
    max(abs(corm))
  } else if (length(corm)==4){
  cormf <- corm[2:nrow(corm),2:ncol(corm)]
  cormf <- 0
  max(abs(cormf))
  } else {
    cormf <- corm[2:nrow(corm),2:ncol(corm)]
    diag(cormf) <- 0
    max(abs(cormf))
  }
}
```

then simply run dredge specifying the number of predictor variables and including the max.r function:

```
options(na.action = na.fail)
Allmodels <- dredge(Fullmodel, rank = "AIC", m.lim=c(0, 3), extra= max.r) 
Allmodels[Allmodels$max.r<=0.6, ] ##Subset models with max.r <=0.6 (not collinear)
NCM <- get.models(Allmodels, subset = max.r<=0.6) ##Retrieve models with max.r <=0.6 (not collinear)
model.sel(NCM) ##Final model selection table
```

This works for lme4 models. For nlme models see: https://github.com/rojaff/dredge_mc

Comment: Please explain more and do not only link to external sources but explain them here as well.